# Fold on “short form of here document”

Tags: bash, notepad++, ksh

Apologies for the x-post from stackoverflow, but there appear to be views of [notepad++] here.

According to the `man ksh` or `man bash` page (RHEL 6.6.0)

`<<< word`

is the equivalent of:

`<< EOF
word
EOF`

How to get the Notepad++ style configurator (Language:Shell) to recognize not to fold on `<<<` ?

Folds nicely on the long form but folds to the end of file on the short form.

Thanks.

Edit - added screenshot to clarify following @PeterCJ's response. Seems it may be related folding within functions - nevertheless ...

[image]

Following his response, updated from 6.5.3 (problem to 6.8.8). Problem exists in 6.7+ and is solved in 6.8+.

Answer (score 1):

For me, Notepad++ properly folds on `<< EOF`, but doesn't fold on `<<< singleline`. [image: (screenshot here)]

Perhaps you have a older version of NPP or a plugin.  Try upgrading to NPP 6.8.8, or looking into whether plugins need upgrading.  Full version info at  menu:`? > Debug Info`: mine looks like

```
    Notepad++ v6.8.8
    Build time : Dec 10 2015 - 01:11:37
    Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
    Admin mode : ON
    Local Conf mode : OFF
    OS : Windows 7
    Plugins : ComparePlugin.dll dbgpPlugin.dll mimeTools.dll NppConverter.dll NppExec.dll NppExport.dll NppFTP.dll NppTextFX.dll PluginManager.dll
```

You can check for available plugin updates at `Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager` and select the `Updates` tab.  If any of your plugins need updating, then select the plugin and choose <kbd>Update</kbd>.

If you don't get more direct answers here, you might want to go to [Notepad++ Community: Help Wanted](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/category/4/help-wanted) forum and ask there, including a screenshot similar to mine and a dump from your `? > Debug Info`.  And if you get it solved, post and accept an answer back here (and point the SO x-post here) for the good of the superuser community.

Comment: There goes the tumbleweed prize! Was running v 6.5.3. I really wanted to avoid upgrading to 6.8 as it marks all sorts of plugins as unstable and there really were not any otherwise compelling features or fixes in 6.6, 6.7 to upgrade.

Comment: Glad you found it.  :-)